# Why do I sometimes have a box2Dcrash when I create bodies in LIbgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have been having a recurrent "random" fatal error in the libgdx mini-game I am developping. For what I gathered, it is a box2d native error, related to a body creation. A possible cause of this is the generation of a body during a timestep, but I believe I have taken the appropriate counter measures.

The following case seems similar, but actually was about the removal of objects from an array while looping through it : [Deleting and creating body in libGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082439/deleting-and-creating-body-in-libgdx) .

Regarding my own issue, here is the output of the crash :

< console >

```
EntityManager: entity generation begin ---------
IceSpike: generating physics
IceSpike: generated physics
IceSpike: generating graphics
EntityManager: entity generation registered
IceSpike: generating physics
IceSpike: generated physics
IceSpike: generating graphics
EntityManager: entity generation registered
IceSpike: generating physics
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=5288, tid=0x00000000000013d4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Codage\projects\eclipse\git\spacegame\SpaceGame\android\assets\hs_err_pid5288.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Log file : http://pastebin.com/JjBGnTri

When it comes to the code, I will try to do as simple as possible. Hopefully, I am not cutting part of the issue.

I have an EntityManager which handles the generation and destruction of my entities. All entities in the game inherit from Entity (a big abstract blob). They all have a box2d body, which is generated in `generatePhysics(World physics)`.

**EntityManager**

```
private GameWorld world;
private Array<Entity> generation;
private Array<Entity> generationCpy;
private Array<Entity> trash;
private Array<Entity> trashCpy;

public void update(float delta)
{
    //generate new entities
    Gdx.app.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "entity generation begins ---------");
    if(generation.size != 0)
    {
        generationCpy = new Array<Entity>(generation);
        for (Entity entity : generationCpy)
        {
            entity.generate(world.getPhysics(),world.getAssetManager());
        }
    }

    //destroy old entities
    Gdx.app.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "entity destruction begins ---------");
    if(trash.size != 0)
    {
        trashCpy = new Array<Entity>(trash);
        for(Entity entity : trashCpy)
        {
            trash.removeValue(entity, true);
            entity.destroy(world.getPhysics());
            entity = null;
        }
    }
    Gdx.app.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "entity generation complete ------");
```

**Entity**

```
public final void generate(World physics, AssetManager assetManager)
{
    if(state != EntityState.GENERATED)
    {
        generatePhysics(physics);
        generateGraphics(assetManager);
        setState(EntityState.GENERATED);
    }
    else
        Gdx.app.error(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "entity couldn't be generated. It had allready been generated");
}
```

So far, only the spikes seem to be concerned, and most of the time, everything runs smoothly. Rest of the time, this is the crashing part:

**IceSpikes**

```
@Override
public void generatePhysics(World physics)
{
    Gdx.app.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "generating physics");

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(this.position.cpy().scl(1 / PPM));

    body = physics.createBody(bodyDef);
    body.setBullet(true);

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    Vector2 vertices[] = new Vector2[3];
    vertices[0] = new Vector2(-width/2,-height/2).scl(1f/PPM);
    vertices[1] = new Vector2(0,height/2).scl(1f/PPM);
    vertices[2] = new Vector2(width/2,-height/2).scl(1f/PPM);
    shape.set(vertices);        

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 1f;
    fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = CollisionManager.BIT_PROJECTILE;
    fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = CollisionManager.BIT_PLAYER;

    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    fixture.setUserData(this);

    shape.dispose();

    Gdx.app.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "generated physics");
}
```

This suggests it is due to the timing creation of IceSpikes, which is after a collision (in a world.step()). However, this is precisely the point of my whole entity management system. It generates/removes bodies outside of a world.step(), as seems confirmed by the output.

Also, copied arrays are set up to prevent entities to be removed from the generation and trash array while theyre are being looped through.

I must have overlooked something, but what ? Any idea how to proceed from there ?

Comment: Why was this voted down ? I'm new and I would at least know why, so I can improve my post next time ...

Comment: Someone on the libgdx forum said that this could come for a missusage of the `.scl(1f/PPM)` resulting in bodies that are too small that would then explode. However, I tried to scale them a bit more, and I still have the issue. I'm still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be caused by multiple creation / destruction of the same body, caused by mutiple references in my entityManager. My entity management system is based on listeners. Every entity has an enum EntityState, and the entity manager is notifyed when the state changes. I thought I was ensuring this state was changing only once in the rest of the code, but as it turned out, it didn't.

A simple fix was to add a `if(this.state != state)` condition.

Here's how it looks like now :

```
public final void setState(EntityState state)
{
    if(this.state == state)
        Gdx.app.error(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "the state was allready " + state);
    else
    {
        this.state = state;
        switch(state)
        {
            case CREATED:       notifyCreation(this);       break;
            case GENERATED:     notifyGeneration(this);     break;
            case TO_BE_REMOVED: notifyFlagForRemoval(this); break;
            case INACTIVE:      notifyDestruction(this);    break;
            default : Gdx.app.error(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "entity state became " + state);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the "why" still eludes me a bit, because I was allready taking certain counter measures, like among other things checking if the body was null before destroying it :

```
protected final void destroyBody(World physics)
{
  Gdx.app.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "destroying body" );
  if(body != null)
  {
     final Array<JointEdge> joints = body.getJointList();
     while (joints.size > 0)
     {
        Gdx.app.log("GameWorld", "destroying joint" );
        Joint joint = joints.get(0).joint;
        physics.destroyJoint(joint);
        joints.removeIndex(0);
     }
     physics.destroyBody(body);
  }
  else
  {
     Gdx.app.error(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "entity's body not found. No action taken." );
  }
```

}

As far as I am concerned, this is fixed, even if the fix is very specific to my case and feels somewhat hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

creation and deletion of entity (basically having physics component) should be bound with lock.

creation and deletion must be performed when physics World is unlocked.

```
private World physicsWorld;
private PhysicsSystem physicsSystem;

@Override
protected void initialize() {

    physicsWorld =physicsSystem.getPhysicsWorld();
}

@Override
protected void processSystem() {

    if(!physicsWorld.isLocked()) {
          removeBodyFromWorld();    
          addBodyIntoWorld();
    }
}
```

In removeBodyFromWorld method remove your desired entity and create new body in addBodyIntoWorld method.

Hopefully It may be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid I am already making sure I am not in a step of the physic world. I jadded a condition `if(!world.getPhysics().isLocked())` for the entity generation and removal, just to be sure, but the issue remains. Still, I'm glad you introduced me to the `isLocked()` method. This may become quite handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As to whether you've overlooked something, from the code posted here, you overlooked `shape` with regards to `vertices` (in the `generatePhysics` method).

Nowhere is the polygon instructed to use these vertices (or any other vertices). Some 3 or more vertices have to be set however before creating the fixture that will use the polygon.

Comment: Ah, thank you. How about the code that outputs the `entity generation registered` message? I don't see it and am wanting to inspect its logic also.

Comment: It's from my entity management system. It is based on an EntityState. The EntityManager listens to the state changes, and put the entities in either a generation array, a specific array (projectile/asteroid/collecable...) or the trash. I've come to think that the issue is indeed more likely to come from there. It needs more investigation from my part at the moment (which I'm currently doing), so I guess the post is "on hold".